# Does a Deva's Change Shape Effectively Heal It?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, healing, shapeshifting

If a CR10 Deva uses Change Shape at half health to assume the form of a Stone Golem, do they become a full health Stone Golem? Is there anything preventing this same Deva from changing back into it's natural form when the Stone Golem is about to die, and making its last stand with that (I presume) half-health it initially had in its main form?

Does Change Shape give such monsters an effective HP buffer, or second health bar?

This question presumes the Deva knows the full extent of its powers, and intends to use them to their fullest. (While still fitting the CR10 category for threat!)

Comment: Related (possible duplicates): "[Can polymorphing monsters spam their ability to effectively give themselves a massive health pool?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/142301)", and "[Does an Oni get new HP when it changes shape into a humanoid or large giant?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135958)"

Comment: @Medix2 I couldn't find this when I searched Shape Change, but the Oni question answers my question nicely. Thank you.

Comment: @DVNO, voting to close as a duplicate. It implies no bad perception on you or your question. It is just that it is a waste of effort to repeat the answers. And linking the questions allows for a broader network of synonymous questions leading to the real answer.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### No

> Change Shape: ...
>
> In a new form, the deva **retains its game Statistics** and ability to speak, but its **[things that are not hp]** are replaced by those of the new form, ...

Hit points are retained.